# What is the effect of field "private volatile Interruptible blocker;" in Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I can see that blocker is used when we invoke interrupt() method.
I found that AbstractInterruptibleChannel.wake() and AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end() methods invoke blockOn() implicitly.

**But what do blocker use for?**
**What do "blocker" mean?** I can't sure what to pick after i search in the dictionary. 
**Why do we use this method name : "blockedOn()"?**

```
/* The object in which this thread is blocked in an interruptible I/O
 * operation, if any.  The blocker's interrupt method should be invoked
 * after setting this thread's interrupt status.
 */
private volatile Interruptible blocker;

 void blockedOn(Interruptible b) {
    synchronized (blockerLock) {
        blocker = b;
    }
}


public void interrupt() {
    if (this != Thread.currentThread())
        checkAccess();

    synchronized (blockerLock) {
        Interruptible b = blocker;
        if (b != null) {
            interrupt0();           // Just to set the interrupt flag
            b.interrupt(this);
            return;
        }
    }
    interrupt0();
}
```

Comment: private = only accessible from inside class. volatile = no reading optimization. Interruptible = a class.

Comment: it seems to be used for synchronization. so you have contrrol over what object in synchronizes on